# UNIX socket implementation for Java?

Tags: java, unix, jdbc, unix-socket

I realize that since UNIX sockets are platform-specific, there has to be some non-Java code involved.  Specifically, we're interested in using JDBC to connect to a MySQL instance which only has UNIX domain sockets enabled.

It doesn't look like this is supported, but from what I've read it should be at least possible to write a SocketFactory for JDBC based on UNIX sockets *if* we can find a decent implementation of UNIX sockets for Java.

Has anyone tried this?  Does anyone know of such an implementation?

Comment: Why not just use the JDBC driver for MySQL?

Comment: Because it uses tcp/ip sockets instead of unix domain sockets?

Comment: The better question is "Why not enable TCP/IP and then use the JDBC driver for MySQL?", but sometimes we don't get to make that call :)

Comment: According to Stevens, Unix domain sockets are twice as fast as TCP/IP sockets

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Checkout the JUDS library. It is a Java Unix Domain Socket library...

https://github.com/mcfunley/juds

Comment: I am using juds right now to listen to UDS and i am receiving caught exceptionjava.io.IOException: Unable to open Unix domain socket. Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: @Angel, usually its cause of permission problems. Try to launch your application from root. If it helps - this is definitely permission problem (you need launch app from user having required permission)

Answer (score 26):

You could use junixsocket: https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket

It already provides code for connecting to MySQL from Java (Connector/J) via Unix sockets.

One big advantage compared to other implementations is that junixsocket uses the standard Java Socket API.

Comment: also junixsocket is Apache 2.0 License, where as juds is LGPL

Comment: I can't recommend it. You are not able to stop the accept() method with closing the socket. Only through stopping the thread, which is probably a bad idea..

Comment: @xoned's issue has been fixed a while ago. Please give junixsocket another try. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 16, Unix domain sockets are supported natively by java through  [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) and [ServerSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html) API.

You can find more information about it in [JEP380](https://inside.java/2021/02/03/jep380-unix-domain-sockets-channels/) proposal and implementation example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/core/internet-protocol-and-unix-domain-sockets-nio-example.html).

Comment: But this is for TCP/IP over unix sockets only right? Does Java support Unix datagram sockets, so we can talk to SystemD for example? Lol chat gpt 4 says it can't, but I figured I'd check in with a human;)

Comment: @MohamedHafez Not yet. See: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8297837

Answer (score 4):

The [MariaDB JDBC driver](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j) now supports this and is compatible with the MySQL JDBC driver.

Use a JDBC url like:

`jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/revmgt?localSocket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Worth noting that this library require including the JNA library as it uses JNA to access native unix domain sockets. It works pretty well in my testing.  I saw speed improvements on CPU bound java processes from the offload to native code.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the JNA library. It's a halfway house between pure Java and JNI native code

https://github.com/twall/jna/

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  It looks like we could use JNA to write our own socket implementation, then write a SocketFactory on top of it, though I was hoping to find something already written. :)

Comment: Have a dig in the Jruby source, they use JNA to simulate a lot of pure ruby stuff including fork! There are also examples of a Posix class that should wrap most of the C level functions you need

Answer (score 1):

The [JNR project](https://github.com/jnr) (which is a loose basis for [project panama](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/)) has a [unix socket](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-unixsocket) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

no one has yet mentioned:
https://github.com/sbt/ipcsocket

has worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Some searching on the internet has uncovered the following useful-looking library:

http://www.nfrese.net/software/gnu_net_local/overview.html

[Wayback Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080820110115/http://www.nfrese.net/software/gnu_net_local/doc/javadoc/index.html)

Writing a socket factory should be easy enough.  Once you've done so, you can pass it to your driver [THUSLY](http://mysql.telepac.pt/doc/refman/5.0/en/mxj-driver-launched.html).([Wayback Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080820110115/http://www.nfrese.net/software/gnu_net_local/doc/javadoc/index.html)).

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.mysql.management.driverlaunched.ServerLauncherSocketFactory;

public class ConnectorMXJTestExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hostColonPort = "localhost:3336";

        String driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostColonPort + "/" + "?"
                + "socketFactory="
                + ServerLauncherSocketFactory.class.getName();
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";

        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
            rs.next();
            String version = rs.getString(1);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println(version);
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ServerLauncherSocketFactory.shutdown(hostColonPort);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both URLs lead to 404 as of now.

Comment: @GregDubicki fixed it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, but both wayback links point to same URL. But please don't try to fix it - what is the point of linking to a lib which is so dead that its doc are not available anymore? How would you download it?