# UNIX Domain Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, unix-socket

I see these threads [UNIX socket implementation for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170600/unix-socket-implementation-for-java) and http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=713266.

The second link says that Java already supports UNIX Domain Socket. If that's true what class do I need to implement from Java?.

From the first link, it says that Java does not support UNIX Domain Socket. If you need UNIX Domain Socket you must use a 3rd-party library.

So, which is it?

Comment: The second link (forums.sun.com) is broken and seems to lead to some nowhere leading page of Oracle.  No archive.org found, BTW, sadly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java cannot create or access Unix Domain Sockets without using a 3rd party (native) library. The last comment on the second link above mentions this.

The first link has some good (and correct) information on it.

Comment: As of Java 16, Unix domain sockets are supported natively java with SocketChannel / ServerSocketChannel API.

Answer (score 24):

You could use junixsocket: https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket

It provides AF-UNIX support via a JNI library, utilizing the Java Socket API. It even allows connecting to MySQL from Java (Connector/J) via Unix sockets.

Comment: As at Nov 2015, the *junixsocket* project resides at https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket

Comment: Be careful, it only supports Unix sockets in STREAM mode. Check what your server opens, with `netstat -ux`. See also [Difference between UNIX domain STREAM and DATAGRAM sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953912).

Comment: Followup to @Florian's great comment: On modern systems, `netstat` is often unavailable, whereas the `iproute2` package and its `ss` tool has replaced it. Use `ss -lx` to see processes listening to UNIX domain sockets in this case.

Comment: junixsocket now supports both stream and datagram sockets.

Answer (score 8):

Netty also supports it since version 4.0.26: https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/3344

Comment: Be careful, it only supports Unix sockets in STREAM mode. Check what your server opens, with `netstat -ux`. See also [Difference between UNIX domain STREAM and DATAGRAM sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953912).

Comment: Please note Netty 4.0 only support `epoll(2)` for Unix domain socket, this means it can't be used without Linux.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @Benny in a comment, JDK 16 comes with built-in support for unix domain sockets via [java.net.UnixDomainSocketAdress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/UnixDomainSocketAddress.html) and related classes. You can read more at [JEP-380](https://inside.java/2021/02/03/jep380-unix-domain-sockets-channels/)

Here's a snippit from the JEP:

> var unixAddr = UnixDomainSocketAddress.of("/foo/bar.socket");
> var channel2 = SocketChannel.open(unixAddr);