# Network communication types in Java

Tags: java

I want to create communication between two Java daemons which are hosted on one Operating system. Is there a technology similar to socket pairs like UNIX domain socket(local domain socket) in Java.

Comment: Two java methods or two java processes? Also, don't just tell us what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

[UNIX Domain Socket in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099432/unix-domain-socket-in-java) tells that UNIX domain sockets are not available from java directly. But you can use TCP sockets (even within the same JVM). Then, if one daemon process is launched from another, they can connect by System.in and System.out.