# How to Write Syslog on linux using java

Tags: java, linux, syslog

I want to write Syslog using in java program on linux system. I don't want to use any library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "no libraries" means no 3rd-party libraries.

One approach would be to code your own implementation of the Syslog Protocol; see [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424).  You could do this in pure Java.

**CORRECTION** - Actually, not pure Java.   The syslog protocol (typically) uses UNIX Domain sockets, and there is no built-in Java library functionality for this.  You would need to resort to native code, or a 3rd-party library; see [UNIX Domain Socket in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099432/)

A second approach would be to write a JNI wrapper for the `syslog(3)` C library methods.  Under the hood, this library opens a datagram socket on a local port and (presumably) implements the Syslog Protocol.  So you don't achieve much by doing it this way.

(Note that the C libraries are part of (at least) any GNU/Linux system, so this doesn't count as using a 3rd-party library.  At least, not in my books ...)

Answer (score 0):

I used the system logger with a Runtime like this:

```
public static void log(String TextToLog){
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try{
        r.exec("logger \"Applicationname " + TextToLog + "\"");
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution uses systemd, you can use the following.

```
String logMessage = "some message";
String logIdentifier = "java-app";
String command = "echo " + logMessage + " | systemd-cat -t " + logIdentifier;
new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"bash","-c","eval " + command}).start();
```

To watch in GNU/Linux's terminal, watch for your `logIdentifier`:

> watch -n0.5 sudo journalctl -t "java-app"