# How can Jedis connect to a redis server using a socket connection?

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm having problems figuring out how to use the Jedis library to connect to a redis socket connection.

I know how to connect through a network port:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
//Jedis jedis = new Jedis(unix_socket_path="/tmp/redis.sock");
```

But the socket connection(second in the list) doesn't work.  The commands looked simlair to redis-py(python client) but when I tried the same syntax it didn't work.  I also looked through the jedis sourcecode on github but couldn't see anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Jedis support unix domain sockets.

The constructor with a single parameter only accepts a hostname (using default TCP port).

Java is portable. It is supposed to provide the same API on different platforms. Unix domain sockets are specific to Unix/Linux. So the Java standard API does not support unix domain sockets. There are [separate Java packages for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170600/unix-socket-implementation-for-java), but AFAIK, Jedis do not use them.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Jedis support UNIX domain sockets through custom Socket factories. [Here is an example of how to use it.](https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/e6341ad7a2ffe307877136800fac752065edab57/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/UdsTest.java#L17-L19)