# Does Python or Java support UNIX domain socket in abstract namespace?

Tags: java, python, sockets

[Like this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)

> abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished by the fact
>             that sun_path[0] is a null byte ('\0').  The socket's address in
>             this namespace is given by the additional bytes in sun_path that
>             are covered by the specified length of the address structure.
>             (Null bytes in the name have no special significance.)  The name
>             has no connection with filesystem pathnames.  When the address of
>             an abstract socket is returned by getsockname(2), getpeername(2),
>             and accept(2), the returned addrlen is greater than
>             sizeof(sa_family_t) (i.e., greater than 2), and the name of the
>             socket is contained in the first (addrlen - sizeof(sa_family_t))
>             bytes of sun_path.  The abstract socket namespace is a nonportable
>             Linux extension.

I want to connect the socket which has been create in abstract namespace(@xxx or \0xxx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UNIX socket implementation for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170600/unix-socket-implementation-for-java)

Comment: you can always use `ctypes`; if there's a libc function or in fact a syscall that supports it, you can surely call it with correct arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Support for "Linux abstract socket namespace" has been in Python since version 2.5 2006.

That's according to the source and changelog.
[Misc/HISTORY](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Misc/HISTORY) (note: big file)

> Patch #1062014: AF_UNIX sockets under Linux have a special
>    abstract namespace that is now fully supported.

It's not mentioned in the Python2 docs but *is* explicitly mentioned in the latest
[Python 3 socket docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families)

Have you tried it under Python2?

As for Java, it doesn't even support AF_UNIX sockets directly; it requires JNI.
There are many implementations (search around) but you will almost certainly need to do some C development to get Linux abstract namespace support.

You might try [Jtux](http://www.basepath.com/aup/jtux/)  It's a complete UNIX api library for Java and of course includes AF_UNIX sockets.