# Is it possible to enable remote JMS through UNIX sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, unix, jboss, wildfly

I am using Wildfly 8.1, I am not an expert with JMS queues and I was wondering if it's possible to use UNIX sockets for them.

This is the default JMS connection factories stanza I use:

```
        <jms-connection-factories>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                <transaction mode="xa"/>
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                </entries>
            </pooled-connection-factory>
        </jms-connection-factories>
```

If it's possible, how? I am a bit lost...

**NOTE:** using UNIX sockets (on Linux) is a prerequisite, no I can't use TCP/IP :(

Comment: Don't know if it's really possible. You could try to write custom SocketFactory (using one of java unix socket libraries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170600/unix-socket-implementation-for-java) and provide it somehow to your JMS server and client.

Comment: ugh..writing a SocketFactory is a bit beyond what I can support...