# How can one connect to a Unix socket using akka?

Tags: scala, akka, unix-socket

While it is relatively easy to connect to an java.net.InetSocketAddress using TCP or UDP in akka, there seems to be no equivalent for SocketAddress and Unix-sockets in the API.

For my current project i need to connnect to the [Docker](http://docker.io) Remote-API using a Unix-Socket. Is there some way to do this using akka or do i need to use a different approach?

Comment: I don't think there's any standard means of JVM communication with Unix domain sockets. There are several JNI-based libraries out there, Google "java unix socket" and there they are. But I've no idea how good or well-supported they are. See e.g. https://github.com/mcfunley/juds https://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/ https://github.com/jnr/jnr-unixsocket/tree/master/src/main/java/jnr/unixsocket/ See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170600/unix-socket-implementation-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpakka (Akka's reactive stream implementation) has an implementation that supports UNIX domain sockets : https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/unix-domain-socket.html

As the name implies : No supported on Win32.